# Unwanted line break with \raggedleft, \centering or \raggedright

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, tex-core, box

In the following example, I get unwanted line breaks for text "Dest-Addr". The result is correct for text "Hello-World". The result is also correct if I change font size to `10pt` or `12pt`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{Hello-World}
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 Hello-World} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedright Hello-World} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \centering Hello-World}   \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedleft Hello-World}  \box2

\setbox0=\hbox{Dest-Addr}
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 Dest-Addr} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedright Dest-Addr} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \centering Dest-Addr}   \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedleft Dest-Addr}  \box2

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Where do these unwanted line breaks come from?
2. How can I get rid of these line breaks?

I need to use `\raggedleft`, `\centering` and `\raggedright` since in my package I need to compare and get the minimal width of several text lines and put them in a `vbox` (similar to `varwidth` package). Also I can not put them in a `hbox` for some other reasons.

Comment: I get no linebreaks with pdftex texlive 2021  nor with luatex, but I do with xetex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens with xetex it seems.

You can prevent hyphenation by setting the exhyphenpenalty to the maximumn

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{Hello-World}
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 Hello-World} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedright Hello-World} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \centering Hello-World}   \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedleft Hello-World}  \box2


\setbox0=\hbox{Dest-Addr}
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 Dest-Addr} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedright \exhyphenpenalty10000 Dest-Addr} \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \centering   \exhyphenpenalty10000 Dest-Addr}   \box2
\setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\wd0 \raggedleft  \exhyphenpenalty10000 Dest-Addr}  \box2



\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it a bug of XeTeX? Are there any other solutions, since I need to handle short text lines and breakable long text lines in the same commands and \exhyphenpenalty10000 is not good for the latter case?

Comment: @L.J.R. I was away from cpmputer so didn't investigate further, it's certainly surprising behaviour, you could raise it on the xetex list, the xetex developers are not here, I suspect it's \rounding error in passing lengths between tex and harfbuzz, but I'm not sure.,

Comment: @L.J.R. with `\raggedright` you don't (normally) get hyhpenation unless the word is longer than the text width  so stopping hyphenation may not be an issue

Comment: looks like a bug in XeTeX. Add 1sp to the width of box 0 and no break happens. I think this should be discussed on xetex list.

Comment: I have submit a bug here: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/185/